# How to get "maximum range" from an array

Tags: php

Index is 00 to 23 (24-hour time)

What I am trying to accomplish is to get largest maximum range.

Each array will have a maximum of 24 elements. Of these, I want to get all the ones which are high (a range).

So, 
for first array - 10,16,19,19 
second - 18,19,20
third - 9,11.

```
Array
(
    [00] => 10
    [01] => 19
    [02] => 10
    [03] => 4
    [04] => 1
    [13] => 16
    [14] => 2
    [15] => 5
    [16] => 2
    [17] => 3
    [18] => 1
    [19] => 1
    [20] => 1
    [21] => 5
    [22] => 1
    [23] => 2
)

Array
(
    [09] => 6
    [10] => 20
    [11] => 18
    [12] => 19
    [13] => 3
    [15] => 11
    [16] => 9
    [18] => 10
)
Array
(
    [00] => 4
    [01] => 3
    [12] => 4
    [16] => 4
    [21] => 9
    [22] => 11
    [23] => 6
)
```

The problem is, these values could get changed entirely, like this one -

```
Array
(
    [13] => 117
    [14] => 221
    [15] => 211
    [16] => 145
    [17] => 23
    [18] => 15
    [19] => 1
)
```

Any solution for this?

Thank you,people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want (although it's not very clear what is a "high" value) can be accomplished with asort(). If you sort your array numerically:

```
asort($yourarray, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Then you can just retrieve the first elements from the sorted array. You don't even specify how many elements should be retrieved, but I'm guessing it's 3, although you don't seem to want anything below 10, so just use array_slice() to extract the last three elements and if any of them is lower than 10 discard it.

Putting it all together would give something like:

```
asort($yourarray, SORT_NUMERIC);
$top3 = array_slice($yourarray, -3, null, true)
$filtered = array_filter($top3, function($v) {return $v > 10;});
```

Note: I used Mchl example on the final part of my answer.

Comment: Uh, I don't have any way to determine the total number of elements myself. I don't see any other way to do what I am trying to.

Comment: You don't know how many "high" values you might get? Ok... so exactly what is a "high" value anyway?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit unclear how you want to choose which values are 'high', but:

In PHP 5.3+

```
$filetered = array_filter($yourArray, function($v) {return $v > 10;});
```

Will return array with values higher than 10.

In PHP <5.3 you will need to createa callback function instead of passing a closure to array_filter.

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and than [max()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) to get the maximum key value:

```
$keys = array_keys($myArray);

$maxKey = max($keys);
```

Comment: Uh, I want to get "range" of maximum values, haven't tested the function above but looks like it will give me only the largest one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter()` to filter out those values that are not within the range:

```
function is_between_10_and_20($v)
{
    return ($v >= 10 && $v <= 20);
}

$result = array_filter($arr, "is_between_10_and_20")
```